# how to center the image using css on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am using background `img` on the `html` tag and the `img` is not on the center. I use `background size: cover;` and it does not work how i would like it to work

```
<section class="section-a">
  <h1 class="main-header-sec-a">Bienvendio a Vida Excotica</h1>
</section>

.section-a{
  background-image: url('/img/waffles.jpeg');
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This is the outcome

[image]

This is what I have

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also scale the image like this:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6h4up90v/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

That's should do the work.

I also recommend that you read the following information:

- [background-position, MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)
- [background-position, W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try adding this:

```
background: url(images/image.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain what is happening?

Comment: top left of the screen = 0% 0%, so setting 50% 50% centers the image vertically and horizontally

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact use `background-size: cover;`, but because this usually ends up cutting the image, you must to also specify the `background-position` property. so your code would end up like this:

```
#myDivID {
  background: url(myImageUrl); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

also, if you want to imporve compativility with older versions of browsers, you can use the background-size prefixed, appending the following to your code:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

see full code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/awrstbn9/9/
Of course there are other ways to achieve this, but (in my opinion) this is the recomended one.